# How to query closest date and display the specific data

Tags: mysql

Hi guys i have a problem displaying a data from my query code.
I want to display a data from the closest date today. Below is my sample data and my output data that i want to display.

```
Landing Area data

|landing_id| id_number| address |
---------------------------------
|    1     | 00012345 | Ozamiz  |
|    2     | 00012346 | Tudela  |
|    3     | 00012347 | Nailon  |
|    4     | 00012348 | Taboo   |
|    5     | 00012349 | Jimenez |
|    6     | 00012350 | Tangub  |
---------------------------------

Percentage data

|percent_id| landing_id | percentage |     date_added     |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     1      |     9      |2018-10-08 21:42:22 |
|    2     |     1      |    12      |2018-10-03 20:43:32 |
|    3     |     1      |    43      |2018-10-15 19:43:49 |
|    4     |     3      |    22      |2018-10-10 15:43:56 |
|    5     |     3      |    77      |2018-10-12 18:44:03 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And this is my query code.

```
SELECT fish_landing.landing_id, 
    percentage.landing_id as percentage_landing_id, 
    percentage.percentage, 
    percentage.date_added 
FROM percentage 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN fish_landing ON percentage.landing_id = fish_landing.landing_id 
ORDER BY fish_landing.landing_id ASC
```

The output of my code is this, where the date_added and the percentage is not exact.

```
|percent_id| percentage |     date_added     |
----------------------------------------------
|    1     |     9      |2018-10-08 21:42:22 |
|    2     |            |                    |
|    3     |    22      |2018-10-10 15:43:56 |
|    4     |            |                    |
|    5     |            |                    |
|    6     |            |                    |
----------------------------------------------
```

And the output data that I want to display is the table below, where the percentage that has a latest date_added in every landing_id will be display.

```
|landing_id| percentage |     date_added     | address |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    1     |     43     |2018-10-15 19:43:49 | Ozamiz  |
|    2     |            |                    |         |
|    3     |     77     |2018-10-12 18:44:03 | Nailon  |
|    4     |            |                    |         |
|    5     |            |                    |         |
|    6     |            |                    |         |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope you can help me in my problem.

Comment: try with `ORDER BY fish_landing.landing_id DESC`

Comment: Note that `RIGHT JOIN` is a vanishingly rare thing.

Comment: @Strawberry how i can modify my code to display the exact data? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get maximum date_added for a landing_id in a separate derived table and use it for joining.

Try the following:

```
SELECT fish_landing.landing_id, 
       percentage.percentage, 
       percentage.date_added, 
       fish_landing.address  
FROM fish_landing 
LEFT JOIN percentage ON percentage.landing_id = fish_landing.landing_id 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT landing_id, MAX(date_added) AS max_date_added 
            FROM percentage 
            GROUP BY landing_id) AS dt 
  ON dt.landing_id = percentage.landing_id AND 
     dt.max_date_added = percentage.date_added
ORDER BY fish_landing.landing_id ASC
```

Comment: Error occurred - [Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'percentage'

Comment: @UnusInstarOmnium  check the updated answer. also ensure that column names are according to ur table structure. Your question has conflicting column names (date_recorded and date_added)

Comment: @Strawberry yes we can use correlated subqueries as well - that's one another way possible

Comment: Still showing the error, I already selected the column date_added - [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'date_added' in 'field list'

Comment: @UnusInstarOmnium please check what is the column name for data in your `percentage` table

Comment: It was all going so well :-(

Comment: @Strawberry actually I am confused that Inner join may actually restrict the dataset if there are nulls on second table.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya its okay the code is running, but the problem is the data is not closest to the date has been display.. I want to display the closest date_added nad the other will be not display.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya how to show only one latest date_added?

Comment: @UnusInstarOmnium what do you mean ? What will be expected output as per the sample data ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I want only to display the data like this image https://ibb.co/eQ9JY0.